# How can I apply the Result.withDefault function to a function that produces a Result

Tags: json, functional-programming, decode, elm

I've got this function that decodes JSON

```
type alias Item =
    { title : String
    , description : String
    , price : Float
    , imageUrl : String
    }

itemDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder Item
itemDecoder =    
    D.map4 ItemData
        (D.field "title" D.string)
        (D.field "description" D.string)
        (D.field "price" D.float)
        (D.field "imageUrl" D.string)

decodeItem : Json.Decode.Value -> Item
decodeItem =
    Json.Decode.decodeValue itemDecoder
```

The error I get from the compiler is that decodeItem produces a

`Json.Decode.Value -> Result Json.Decode.Error Item`

instead of a

`Json.Decode.Value -> Item`

How can I wrap the output of `decodeItem` with a `Result.withDefault` so that it produces a valid item or it returns an empty `Item`. The empty `Item` would be the first argument to `Result.withDefault`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you have a function which returns an empty `Item`, for example `emptyItem`, you just need to perform the steps you've described:

- Wrap the output of decodeItem with a `Result.withDefault`
- The empty `Item` would be the first argument to `Result.withDefault`

As a result:

```
decodeItem : D.Value -> Item
decodeItem value =
    Result.withDefault emptyItem (D.decodeValue itemDecoder value)
```

`emptyItem` can be a function which returns `Item` record with default values, for example:

```
emptyItem : Item
emptyItem = Item "" "" 0 ""
```

Or some reasonable defaults, that make sense to you

Comment: Got it thanks! I felt like I was missing something, cos there's so little code compared to javascript!